# Is there a simplified way to model charged particle decay?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, radiation

I've been thinking about building an art-focused simulation of a bubble chamber. I'd rather start with a basis in physics rather than just tuning variables until I have cloud chamber-like pictures. I don't have a problem simulating the motion of a particle though a magnetic field but unfortunately most of the stuff governing the particle decay and interactions is way over my head. What I can grasp seems computationally to heavy for my purposes.

I'm hoping someone could put me on the right track to finding or deriving a more simplistic model that would work well for an approach that only strives to be accurate enough to capture the "look and feel" without any sort of deep accuracy. Specifically I'd like to recreate images like this one https://cds.cern.ch/record/39474

Comment: do you really mean the whole mess? or the lambda which is the <  tracks?

Comment: GEANT 4 is the free open-source software used by CERN for simulating the interactions of high-energy particles with matter.  I haven't used it myself, and it is probably very technical, but you may want to look into it.  It is supposed to be versatile enough that NASA also uses it for simulating cosmic rays on spacecraft.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geant4

Comment: I think I do mean the whole mess, from an artistic standpoint the lower energy charged particles that form spirals as they lose energy are the ones I'm most interested in. I'm hoping that there's large parts of the complexity that I can ignore if I'm only trying to make art, but perhaps that's not the case.

GEANT4 is likely overkill for my purposes, but I'll give it a shot this weekend to see if I can get anything out of it, thanks for pointing it out.